# How to pass data from context.Forward and how to get the item in child dialog

Tags: c#, botframework

I have one main dialog: `MainDialog()` and I want to send a message to child dialog: `ChildDialog()` using `context.Forward()`.

I want to access the message I sent from `MainDialog` in `StartAsync` method of `ChildDialog`. The `StartAsync` method of `ChildDialog` has `Context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync)`. Based on the message I got from `MainDialog` (I want to send **YES** or **NO** string to `childDialog`), I want to take action.

If it is **YES**, I don't want to wait in `ChildDialog` and directly pass the message to `MessageReceivedAsync` handler.

How can I do this? I've looked at [After call context.Forward, how to get the item in child dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288842/after-call-context-forward-how-to-get-the-item-in-child-dialog), but it is related to `LuisDialog`.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

While you can't pass data to `StartAsync` as an argument, there are a few ways you can pass data to your child dialog. Since you have control over your dialog's constructor, you can pass data as an argument to the constructor like this:

```
context.Forward(new ChildDialog(data), MessageReceivedAsync, item, token);
```

If you store the data in a property or field of your `ChildDialog` class, you'll be able to access that data in `StartAsync`.

You may have noticed `context.Forward`'s `item` parameter. That's another way you can pass data to your child dialog, but it won't be available until after `StartAsync` has run. That said, you might want to reevaluate the design of your program flow. You say:

> If it is **YES**, I don't want to wait in `ChildDialog` and directly pass the message to `MessageReceivedAsync` handler.

If you have `context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync)` in your `StartAsync` method then you already won't wait in `ChildDialog`. This may be confusing, but even though you're calling `context.Wait` the message will immediately be passed along to `MessageReceivedAsync` because `context.Forward` sends the message to the dialog immediately after it calls `StartAsync`.

I'm guessing you want your bot to wait until the user sends another message if you pass "NO" to your child dialog. I don't know what you're trying to do with your bot, but I would consider not even starting your child dialog until the next turn in that case. If you really want to start the dialog and immediately wait, you might consider having two different `ResumeAfter` delegates:

```
[Serializable]
public class ChildDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    private string _data;

    public ChildDialog(string data)
    {
        _data = data
    }

    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        if (_data.Equals("YES"))
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Wait(WaitAsync);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        // Respond to a message from the user
    }

    private async Task WaitAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
}
```

Please have a look at the documentation for more information about dialogs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-dialogs?view=azure-bot-service-3.0